# Pandas: for every row value in several columns, turn it into a new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` with a bunch of pictures every row. What I want to do is turn it into a format for machine learning, so every pic will predict the list of attributes.

For all pics, turn them into a row and the rest of the row would be the original row it was on. It will be easier to demonstrate it visually:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Mark', 'Laura', 'Adam'],
                   'City':['Lisbon', 'Montreal', 'Lisbon'],
                   'Picture Col 1': ['Pic 47', 'Pic 36', 'Pic 15'],
                   'Picture Col 2': ['Pic 54', 'Pic 84', 'Pic 48']})
```

```
    Name      City Picture Col 1 Picture Col 2
0   Mark    Lisbon        Pic 47        Pic 54
1  Laura  Montreal        Pic 36        Pic 84
2   Adam    Lisbon        Pic 15        Pic 48
```

Expected result:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Picture':['Pic 47', 'Pic 36', 'Pic 15', 'Pic 54', 'Pic 84', 'Pic 48'],
                    'Name': ['Mark', 'Laura', 'Adam', 'Mark', 'Laura', 'Adam'],
                    'City':['Lisbon', 'Montreal', 'Lisbon', 'Lisbon', 'Montreal', 'Lisbon']})
```

```
  Picture   Name      City
0  Pic 47   Mark    Lisbon
1  Pic 36  Laura  Montreal
2  Pic 15   Adam    Lisbon
3  Pic 54   Mark    Lisbon
4  Pic 84  Laura  Montreal
5  Pic 48   Adam    Lisbon
```

Every picture should be a predictor to multiple attributes. Is this `melt`, `pivot`, `unstack`? I wouldn't even know.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Name','City'],value_name='Picture').drop('variable',axis=1)
print(new_df[['Picture','Name','City']])
  Picture   Name      City
0  Pic 47   Mark    Lisbon
1  Pic 36  Laura  Montreal
2  Pic 15   Adam    Lisbon
3  Pic 54   Mark    Lisbon
4  Pic 84  Laura  Montreal
5  Pic 48   Adam    Lisbon
```

Comment: Good answer, but I do not use drop if then we are going to reindex or use loc to select certain columns, that is, we either delete all the columns with drop or we reindex but both methods I think is somewhat inefficient. But good answer :)

Comment: @ansev thanks :-) well for small time operations i think thisis ok

Answer (score 1):

We can do:

```
( df1.melt(['Name','City'],value_name='Picture')
     .reindex(columns = ['Picture'] + [*df1.columns[:-2]]) )
     #.loc[:,['Picture','Name','City']] )
     #.reindex(columns = ['Picture','Name','City']) )
```

or

```
( df1.set_index(['Name','City'])
     .stack()
     .rename('Picture')
     .reset_index()
     .reindex(columns = ['Picture'] + [*df1.columns[:-2]]) )
```

**Output**

```
  Picture   Name      City
0  Pic 47   Mark    Lisbon
1  Pic 36  Laura  Montreal
2  Pic 15   Adam    Lisbon
3  Pic 54   Mark    Lisbon
4  Pic 84  Laura  Montreal
5  Pic 48   Adam    Lisbon
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have answered your own question. `melt` can do what you want. You'll just have to drop the "variable" column after you melt the dataframe (it's the column which lists whether the pic is from Picture Col 1 or Picture Col 2).

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html